# How to identify the highlight groups in use on a particular character?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm new to `vim` and bumped into a problem.

Short question -- will `vim` tell me why it chose to highlight certain text in a certain way?

Long question --

I'm using `vimdiff` to compare two files, and the "DiffChange" highlight uses a purple background.

However, the files I'm diff'ing are `puppet` files, and there are quite a few possible highlights that show the text in the same purple color.

So what I'd really like to do is move to a specific character and have `vim` tell me "this character is subject to the following highlights" so that I know which one (for the text color) needs to be changed.

Is that possible?

Comment: I love how my question, dated Aug 4 2017, is now marked as a "closed / duplicate" of a question that is dated Jan 4 2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from my .vimrc (all in one line):

`nnoremap <M-i> :echo "hi<" . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name") . '> trans<' . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),0),"name") ."> lo<" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"name") . ">"<CR>`

move to your character and press Alt-i.

You may want to choose a different key for this mapping.

Comment: What is the difference between `hi`, `trans` and `lo`