# How to know which highlighting group is used for the background of a word?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, terminal, highlight

Vim highlights the *background* of certain words (e.g. when doing spellchecking) in a way that I would like to change (because the background and the word itself are almost of the same color, which makes the whole thing illegible). How is it possible to determine which "background" (?) highlighting group (?) vim is using, so that it can be customized?

I did find an [apparently similar-looking question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/how-to-identify-the-highlight-groups-in-use-on-a-particular-character), but its answer does not offer the simplest response (Ralf's answer below is simpler already), and more importantly, it doesn't cover the colors of the *background* (it displays the highlighting group of the text *foreground*).

Comment: I put together [vim-synstax](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax) for this, though I believe it relies techniques similar to the posted answer under the hood.

Comment: Just because an answer isn't simple doesn't mean it isn't correct...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify the highlight groups in use on a particular character?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/how-to-identify-the-highlight-groups-in-use-on-a-particular-character)

Comment: Just because an answer isn't simple doesn't mean there isn't any simple answer. :) The answer by Ralf below is already about 3 times simpler.

Comment: More importantly, the answer you link to is about the text foreground, whereas the text background is what is problematic _and_ not reported by the answer.

Comment: Plugin answer: https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease defines `zS` to show you the syntax groups determining the syntax highlighting under the cursor.

Comment: As the question and the accepted answer (by me) somehow diverge, I voted to close this question. The question itself is a duplicate, but in fact other information was needed (hl-groups of spell checking). Eric, I guess you got the info you needed.

Comment: Did you see that the question and your answer were updated since you answered it? It should be clear now that the question is not a duplicate; the answer to the other question is definitely not an answer to this question.

Comment: Just because the other question doesn't have a good answer doesn't mean the *question* isn't a duplicate. At any rate, I marked the other question as a duplicate of this one, in spite of being older, as this one has the most useful answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the following in my vimrc:

```
command SynID  echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

Move the cursor to the word you are interested in and then execute `:SynID`.

The spell checker can set the background of the word independently. It uses the names "SpellBad", "SpellCap", "SpellLocal" and "SpellRare". Definition can be printed with `:highlight SpellBad`, etc., so that you can probably recognize which style is used by the spell checker that causes a problem for you. Also see `:help hl-SpellBad`.

Comment: That's very close to the solution I was referring to in the question: do you know by any chance of any more direct way of getting the same information?

Comment: PS: This doesn't actually give all the information needed: for example, the cursor is in a vim comment and some of the words are highlighted, and this returns "vimComment" on both highlighted and non-highlighted words. Maybe what I am looking for here is not a "highlighting group"? Or maybe more information can be obtained?

Comment: Strange. I have this vim comment: `" Mapping: This is a "Test"`. On `Mapping` it returns "vimCommentTitle", on `"Test"` it returns "vimCommentString" and on the rest of the line it returns "vimLineComment".

Comment: I observe the same. Now I am pretty sure that what I need to have is the style of the text _background_ (not of the text per se), which is set by the spell checker. I'll update the question.

Comment: @EricLebigot The spell checker uses the names "SpellBad", "SpellCap", "SpellLocal" and "SpellRare". Definition can be printed with `:highlight SpellBad` etc. Also see `:help hl-SpellBad`.

Comment: You got it, thanks a bunch! I included your comment in the answer.