# How to check what of highlight is the word on cursor?

Tags: highlight

I found this article,
[How to know which highlighting group is used for the background of a word?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/how-to-know-which-highlighting-group-is-used-for-the-background-of-a-word)

however, it prints out something not what I look for.

It prints out like

```
VimCommand
VimOption
...
```

but I look for something like

```
Normal
ColorColumn
CursorColumn
CursorLine
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

```
nnoremap <Leader>nani :echo "hi<" . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name") . '> trans<' . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),0),"name") ."> lo<" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"name") . ">"<CR>
```

This does it using `synIDtrans`.
I want to get the color directly as well though